# What is a 4-wire voltage measurement?

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement, precision

I am working with a [Fluke 8508A](http://assets.fluke.com/manuals/8508A___umeng0300.pdf), an 8.5-digit table-top multimeter. To my surprise, one of the menu options is a 4-wire DC voltage measurement.

I know how 4-wire *resistance* measurements work, but I am at a loss how a 4-wire *voltage* measurement would be beneficial. Does it give higher precision, and if so, how?

Comment: ~200 pages in the manual, can you give me a hint where it talks about 4-wire voltage measurement?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold On page 3-5 (i.e. page 39 in the Acrobat Reader)

Comment: Laser-diode drivers often have “4-wire voltage measurement” features, but I think that’s something different.  Those are measuring the diode voltage when current is driven, more like a resistance measurement, though they call it voltage.

Comment: I don't the info in the manual answer's the OP's question -- at least not mine which is exactly the title of this post.  How does a 4-wire voltage measurement work?

Answer (score 1):

From page 3-5 (thanks)
"4wV Allows operation with calibrators which provide a remote 4 wire sensing
capability by providing connections between INPUT HI and SENSE HI and
between INPUT LO and SENSE LO.
The 4wV annunciator in the left-hand display indicates that 4-wire sensing
is active."

I'm going to guess it's similar as remote sensing on a DC power supply.  When you want to exclude the voltage drop along the wires.  So very similar to 4-wire resistance.

Comment: A little more from the manual in AC voltage measurement:  *Allows operation with calibrators which provide a remote 4 wire sensing capability by providing, at an internal  reference plane within the DMM, connections between **INPUT HI** and **SENSE HI** and between **INPUT LO** and **SENSE LO** .  Use of an internal reference plane can be helpful in 4wire AC, AC transfer, or 4wire AC – DC transfer applications.*